# How to parse JSON in Apex Programming?

Tags: apex

I am new to the Apex Programming. How can I create the Lead Object? Assuming FirstName and LastName etc... are fields of Case Object.

```
String jsonstring = '[{"FirstName":"Balaji","LastName":"Malemarpuram","Company":"Oracle","City":"Hyderabad","State":"AP","PostalCode":500081,"Phone":9502026343,"Status":"Open - Not Contacted","Tags":[]},{"FirstName":"Sreevardhan","LastName":"Malemarpuram","Company":"Appshark","City":"Hyderabad","State":"AP","PostalCode":500081,"Phone":95055556343,"Status":"Open - Not Contacted","Tags":[]}]';

JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonString);
```

As per inputs from I tried below in anonymous window. I see the below error:

```
String jsonstring = '[{"FirstName":"Balaji","LastName":"Malemarpuram","Company":"Oracle","City":"Hyderabad","State":"AP","PostalCode":500081,"Phone":9502026343,"Status":"Open - Not Contacted","Tags":[]},{"FirstName":"Sreevardhan","LastName":"Malemarpuram","Company":"Appshark","City":"Hyderabad","State":"AP","PostalCode":500081,"Phone":95055556343,"Status":"Open - Not Contacted","Tags":[]}]';
List<Lead> leadList = (List<Lead>)JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, List<Lead>.class);
System.debug('SIZE : '+leadList.size());
```

Error

```
 Column: 1
System.JSONException: QueryResult must start with '{'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a parser for this.

Apex has a functionality called - [de-serialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm).

You could just do a

```
String jsonstring = '[{"FirstName":"Balaji","LastName":"Malemarpuram","Company":"Oracle","City":"Hyderabad","State":"AP","PostalCode":500081,"Phone":9502026343,"Status":"Open - Not Contacted","Tags":[]},{"FirstName":"Sreevardhan","LastName":"Malemarpuram","Company":"Appshark","City":"Hyderabad","State":"AP","PostalCode":500081,"Phone":95055556343,"Status":"Open - Not Contacted","Tags":[]}]';
List<Lead> leadList = (List<Lead>)JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, List<Lead>.class);
```

You will have the list of Leads on `leadList` variable.

Comment: do you think this will work? I think it needs some modification.

Comment: Yes, it definitely should work. What kind of modification are you suggesting? If you are talking about the field api names, they are same in case and lead.

Comment: the second line of answer is fine but the json string is not appropriate. I tried in my org and it throws error.

Comment: Weird! I just tried it. Working fine.

Comment: I am also facing the issue..   `lstlead = (List<Lead>)JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, List<Lead>.class);` This is causing an issue `17:20:47:010 FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: QueryResult must start with '{'`

Comment: Okay, my org doesn't have tag activated, thats why it worked. Can you post a JSON of a case record with active tags?